# Append to Python dictionary from method

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have this dictionary called biography

```
self.biography = {'Name' : '', 'Age' : 0, 'Nationality' : '', 'Position' : 0, 'Footed' : ''}
```

I also have this method called create_player

```
def create_player(self):
    name = input('Player name: ')
    age = int(input('Player age: '))
    nationality = input('Nationality: ')
    position = input('Position: ')
    footed = input('Footed: ')
```

How can I go through this list and append to biography dictionary, matching up the various attribute names with their values accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_player(self):
    name = input('Player name: ')
    age = int(input('Player age: '))
    nationality = input('Nationality: ')
    position = input('Position: ')
    footed = input('Footed: ')

    # afterwards
    self.biography["Name"] = name
    self.biography["Age"] = age
    ... and so on ...
```

Just access your `biography` dict like an (associative) array.
If you want an ordered output, use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class myClass():
    biography = OrderedDict()
    def setupDict(self):
        self.biography["Name"] = "Some name here"
```

Comment: the only issue is that it does not print out the dictionary in the order I set it up in ? other than that it works a dream

Comment: @NewUser123: Does the order matter?

Comment: yes because I'd like to print it out like a real bio would look, with name first etc

Comment: Then the solution would be to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), since a dict is normally unordered in `Python`.

Comment: @NewUser123: Added example code for an ordered dictionary.

Comment: @RahulKP: You are right, but the code shows the general approach. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_player(self):
    for key in self.biography.keys():
        val = input('Player {}: '.format(key.lower()))
        self.biography[key] = int(val) if val.strip().isdigit() else val
```

Comment: So create problem while update age right ?. It's read in the form of string.

Comment: @RahulKP piece of cake ;)

Comment: @ Sergey Gornostaev Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_player(self):
    self.biography['Name'] = input('Player name: ')
    self.biography['Age'] = int(input('Player age: '))
    self.biography['Nationality'] = input('Nationality: ')
    self.biography['Position'] = input('Position: ')
    self.biography['Footed'] = input('Footed: ')
```

try this.