# iterating over user input and inserting into python dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

```
self.biography = {'name' : '', 'age' : 0, 'nationality' : '', 'position' : '', 'footed' : ''}

   def create_player(self):
        name = input('Player name: ')
        age = int(input('Player age: '))
        nationality = input('Nationality: ')
        position = input('Position: ')
        footed = input('Footed: ')
        bio_attributes = [name, age, nationality, position, footed]
        for attribute in bio_attributes:
            self.biography[attribute] = bio_attributes
```

I somehow want to iterate through this python method and then place the values into the dictionary, i know I could do something like

```
self.biography["name"] = name
self.biography["age"] = age
```

but this is obviously repeating code so how can i use something like my for loop to make this work?

Comment: I have already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069871/append-to-python-dictionary-from-method/37069996#37069996

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
self.biography = {'Player name' : '', 'Player age' : 0, 'Nationality' : '', 'Position' : '', 'Footed' : ''}
def create_player(self):
    for key in self.biography:
        val = input(key + ': ')
        self.biography[key] = val
```